# Using the rabbitmq plugin in Grails is it possible to define fallback/ failover addresses?

Tags: grails-plugin-rabbitmq

I am converting a Grails project from using ActiveMq to using RabbitMq. Is it possible to configure RabbitMQ with a multiple fallback/ failover addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I put a oad balancer in front of the rabbit mq servers.